# ReactiveSwift: Retry up to n times, then execute some code

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, reactive-swift

Consider the code below

```
func test() -> SignalProducer<String, Error> {
    return SignalProducer<String, Error> { observer, _ in
        ...
    }
}

test()
    .on(value: { s in
        print(s)
    })
    .retry(upTo: 2)
    .start()
}
```

Is there a built-in way to retry n times, then (if it failed all the tries) execute some callback?

It's of course possible to introduce a local counter and count the failures in `.on(failed: _)` and then do something if the counter equals n+1, but is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retry(upTo:)` passes along the error once it's reached its retry limit, so you can use one of the `start` methods that allows you to handle values and an error. For example, using `startWithResult` you could do this (note I haven't tested this code, but it should give you the idea):

```
test()
    .retry(upTo: 2)
    .startWithResult { result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(value):
            print(value)
        case let .failed(error):
            // handle error here
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's important here is the order, adding the `.retry` before the `.on` handlers passes the last error only (the desired effect in this case). I somehow missed that.

Comment: Yeah, each operator actually creates a new signal/producer that wraps the previous one with some logic or transfomation. So `retry` in your original code is going to retry the producer as defined by all the code that comes before it, which includes the `on` side effects.